# Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Tags: r, rstudio, regresión-lineal

estoy intentando aplicar Imputación Múltiple a mi dataset y me da el siguiente error. He buscado motivos y uno de ellos es que alguna variable sea de tipo string, lo que no es mi caso. Dispongo de un dataset de 4 variables y ninguna es string. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme lo agradecería bastante. Adjunto código:

```
install.packages("ALA", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(ALA)
library(mice) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

cholest <- ALA::cholesterol

#defino mis variables:
explanatory = c("id", "treatment", 
                "month")
dependent = "cholesterol"

cholest %>% 
  select(dependent, explanatory) %>% 
  missing_predictorMatrix(
    drop_from_imputed = c("treatment", "cholest")
  ) -> predM

fits = cholest %>% 
  select(dependent, explanatory) %>% 
  mice(m = 4, predictorMatrix = predM) %>% 
  # Run logistic regression on each imputed set
  with(glm(formula(ff_formula(dependent, explanatory)), 
           family="binomial"))
```

Answer (score 0):

corrígeme si me equivoco, quieres hacer una logistica sobre tu data, con tu conjunto de datos actualizado con los datos imputados.

```
fits = cholest %>%
  select(dependent, explanatory) %>%
  mice(m = 4, predictorMatrix = predM)
```

Para recuperar el data con los datos actualizados puedes usar la funcion complete()

```
cholest_completo = mice::complete(fits, 1)
```

Aquí viene la parte en la que te da error, para usar la logística, tu variable dependiente, en este caso cholesterol, debe ser binaria, es decir, tener solo dos resultados posibles.

En este caso debes elegir un criterio para convertirla en una variable del tipo dicotomica, un ejemplo seria decir que cuando el valor es mayor a la media adopte el valor 1 y cuando no sea 0

```
cholest_glm = cholest_completo %>%
  mutate(cholesterol = ifelse(cholesterol > mean(cholesterol), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(cholesterol = as.factor(cholesterol)) %>%
  with(glm(formula(ff_formula(
    dependent, explanatory
  )),
  family = "binomial"))
```

Comment: Buenas Bastian! Lo 1o gracias por ayudar, he modificado el código con tus mejoras y no sé si sigo obteniendo lo que quiero. Intento a partir de una base de datos con NA aplicar Imputación Múltiple a ésta (generar x datasets informados, en este caso 4) y aplicar a todos ellos regresión logística. Luego estudiar los resultados, que es lo que no funciona ahora, siendo ese código: fits %>% 
  getfit() %>% 
  purrr::map(AIC) donde he llamado fits a tu cholest_glm (el error que da es Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "data.frame")